# How to display navigation bar and only show on specific pages in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I am working on an app. The app has a splash screen, then a  tour screen is displayed (if this is the first time a user is running the app). Finally once the user exits the tour screen  they are directed to the main app page. The main page should display a navigation bar (but not the splash or tour screen).

I have all the code below:

1. How do I display the Navigation Bar?
2. How do I restrict which pages can display it?

Thanks

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fyw/pages/navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:fyw/pages/tour.dart';
import 'package:fyw/pages/splash.dart';
import 'package:fyw/pages/login.dart';
import 'package:fyw/pages/home.dart';

var routes = <String, WidgetBuilder>{
  "/tourpage": (BuildContext context) => Tour(),
  "/loginpage": (BuildContext context) => LoginPage(),
  "/homepage": (BuildContext context) => HomePage(),
};

void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(
    theme:
        ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.red, accentColor: Colors.yellowAccent),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: Splash(),
    routes: routes
    ));
```

navigation_bar.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fyw/pages/home.dart';
import 'package:fyw/pages/login.dart';


class NavigationBarController extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavigationBarControllerState createState() =>
      _NavigationBarControllerState();
}

class _NavigationBarControllerState
    extends State<NavigationBarController> {
  final List<Widget> pages = [
    HomePage(),
    LoginPage(),
  ];

  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();

  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  Widget _bottomNavigationBar(int selectedIndex) => BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: (int index) => setState(() => _selectedIndex = index),
        currentIndex: selectedIndex,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add), title: Text('home')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.list), title: Text('login Page')),
        ],
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: _bottomNavigationBar(_selectedIndex),
      body: PageStorage(
        child: pages[_selectedIndex],
        bucket: bucket,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  class Home extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBarController(context),
       );
    }
  }
```